# MySQL select row from two tables even though only one table may have the row

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables, `posts` and `pages`. The `posts` table has more columns than the `pages` table, but other than that they are the same in terms of schema.

If a `slug` is given, the row with the right `slug` could exist in the `pages` table, or the `posts` table. I was thinking of something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE slug = 'about'

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE slug = 'about'
```

but that requires the row with the `slug` of "about" to be in both tables. There's probably a simple `INNER JOIN` I could use, but my SQL knowledge is limited.

To clarify, I want to be able to search across both tables as if they were one.

Here is the `posts` table structure:

```
`slug` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`published` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`content` longtext NOT NULL,
`author` text NOT NULL,
`status` enum('published','draft','trashed') NOT NULL
```

and the `pages` structure:

```
`slug` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`content` longtext NOT NULL,
`menu_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('published','drafted','trashed') NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think your use of `UNION` here is correct...I must be missing something

Comment: @lc. `UNION` will only work if the number of columns being returned for each table is the same and that the datatypes are the same.  Based on the description above `SELECT *` will not work with `UNION` since one table has more columns than the other, unless they limit the columns being returned.

Comment: Please post the two tables' structures and if there is any sample data.

Comment: @bluefeet True and that may just be what the OP was missing. I was just looking at using a union vs a join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use union but you need to specify columns **(col1,col2,..)** the two list should be identical:

```
SELECT col1,col2,.. 
FROM pages 
WHERE slug = 'about' 

UNION

SELECT col1,col2,.. 
FROM posts 
WHERE slug = 'about'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search both tables as if they were one, you really want to use UNION (and not JOIN).

Your query above probably fails because tables have different columns. You should rather specify the columns names in the two sub-queries.